# Calculate a minimum item value to obtain an average threshold value by group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data sample with values grouped by ID and item and I need to determine a minimum value necessary by which to increase a single item to meet an overall Average threshold of 0.90 by ID.

data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Item1", 
"Item2"), class = "factor"), Value.1 = c(0.7894, 0.95, 0.7894
), CurrentAvg = c(0.7894, 0.8697, 0.8697)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I am able to obtain a difference value per item via the syntax below:

```
library(dplyr)
SampDF2<-SampDF %>% 
group_by(ID,Item,CurrentAvg) %>% 
mutate(Value.1.Increase = 0.90-Value.1)
```

Result:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Item1", 
"Item2"), class = "factor"), Value.1 = c(0.7894, 0.95, 0.7894
), CurrentAvg = c(0.7894, 0.8697, 0.8697), Value.1.Increase = c(0.1106, 
-0.0499999999999999, 0.1106)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), vars = c("ID", 
"Item", "CurrentAvg"), labels = structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), Item = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Item1", "Item2"), class = "factor"), CurrentAvg = c(0.7894, 
0.8697, 0.8697)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
), vars = c("ID", "Item", "CurrentAvg"), drop = TRUE), indices = list(
0L, 2L, 1L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L)
```

But this result is not correct for an item value increase that would increase the CurrentAvg by ID to the 0.90 threshold.

Is there any way to do this and also add two new columns (a value increase column that shows the value increase and a NewAvg column to confirm that the new average meets the 0.90 threshold)?

This would be the desired result provided my manual calculation is correct:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Item1", 
"Item2"), class = "factor"), Value.1 = c(0.7894, 0.95, 0.8393
), CurrentAvg = c(0.7894, 0.8697, 0.8697), ValueIncrease = c(0.1106, 
0.04999, 0.04999), NewAvg = c(0.9, 0.89465, 0.89465)), class = "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: @Rui Barradas that appears to result in a vaIue of 0.90 for each row. I edited my question to try to clarify that I need to know what the value is that the item increase needs to be to obtain the overall average by ID of 0.90. Ideally there would be two additional columns, one for the value increase and one for the new average.

Comment: The result is `0.9` per each row because after grouping you only have one data point per group and if length(x) is `1` then `mean(x) == 0.9 => x == 0.9`. If the data point and its mean value are equal, `Value.1 - mean(Value.1)` is zero. Then add `0.9`. With a real, bigger dataset this will not happen.

Comment: @Rui Barradas does the desired result I just added help? I attempted a manual calculation of the amount of increase that would have to occur for either item for ID A2 in order for the overall average to meet the 0.90 threshold for that ID.

Comment: Yes, it helps. But then you will have to group just by `ID`. Something like `SampDF2<-SampDF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(ValueIncrease = 0.9 - mean(Value.1),
         NewAvg = mean(Value.1) + ValueIncrease)`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas We are close but the result in the ValueIncrease column, when added to any Item's Value1 score does not increase the CurrentAvg up to 0.90. The 0.90 result if the CurrentAvg + the ValueIncrease, which does not tell me how much any individual Value1 score much increase in order to bring the CurrentAvg up to 0.90. One could manually increase any Value1 score to try and raise the CurrentAvg up to 0.90, but I have over 1500 ID's.